Error during tokenization with the contract: 0xe83cE6bfb580583bd6A62B4Be7b34fC25F02910D
I have an Alchemy project through which I have received transactions. I would like to tokenize these transactions using the following Python script:
import json
from web3 import Web3

# Codes de couleur ANSI
GREEN = '\033[92m'
RESET = '\033[0m'

# Charger la configuration
with open('config.json') as config_file:
    config = json.load(config_file)

alchemy_url = config['alchemy_url']
private_key = config['private_key']
account_address = config['account_address']
wabbc_contract_address = '###############################################'

# Connectez-vous à Alchemy
w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(alchemy_url))

# Vérifiez la connexion
if not w3.is_connected():
    print("Échec de la connexion à Alchemy")
    exit()

# Charger l'ABI du contrat
with open('contract_abi.json') as abi_file:
    wabbc_abi = json.load(abi_file)

# Obtenir une instance du contrat
wabbc_contract = w3.eth.contract(address=wabbc_contract_address, abi=wabbc_abi)

# Fonction pour générer les tokens WABBC et sauvegarder les transactions
def generate_wabbc_tokens(block_data):
    transactions = []
    nonce = w3.eth.get_transaction_count(account_address)

    for block in block_data:
        block_number = block['number']
        block_hash = block['hash']
        
        for tx in block['transactions']:
            tx_value = tx['value']
            tx_from = tx['from']
            tx_to = tx['to']

            # Tokeniser uniquement les transactions avec une valeur supérieure à zéro
            if tx_value > 0:
                # Tokeniser la transaction
                tx_hash = tokenise_transaction(tx_value, tx_from, tx_to, nonce)
                print(f'Tokenised transaction {tx["hash"]}: {tx_hash}')

                # Ajouter les détails de la transaction au fichier
                transactions.append({
                    'original_tx_hash': tx['hash'],
                    'new_tx_hash': tx_hash,
                    'from': tx_from,
                    'to': tx_to,
                    'value': tx_value,
                    'block_number': block_number,
                    'block_hash': block_hash,
                })

                # Sauvegarder les transactions générées dans un fichier JSON
                with open('generated_transactions.json', 'w') as f:
                    json.dump(transactions, f, indent=4)

                nonce += 1  # Incrémenter le nonce pour chaque transaction

# Fonction pour tokeniser une transaction
def tokenise_transaction(value, from_address, to_address, nonce):
    # Construire la transaction pour générer des tokens
    txn = wabbc_contract.functions.mint(to_address, value).build_transaction({
        'chainId': 1,  # Assurez-vous que cela correspond à votre réseau
        'gas': 1000000,
        'gasPrice': w3.to_wei('10', 'gwei'),  # Augmenter le prix du gaz
        'nonce': nonce,
    })

    # Signer la transaction
    signed_txn = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(txn, private_key=private_key)
    
    # Envoyer la transaction
    tx_hash = w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
    
    return w3.to_hex(tx_hash)

# Lire les transactions depuis le fichier JSON
with open('blocks.json', 'r') as f:
    block_data = json.load(f)

# Générer les tokens WABBC à partir des transactions et sauvegarder les transactions
generate_wabbc_tokens(block_data)

The script runs fine, I am debited, but I do not receive any tokens. When I check on etherscan.io, I see the following message which I do not understand:
"Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [execution reverted]"

Is your mint() function having any modifiers like onlyOwner or so? If yes, then are you using the account (to sign the corresponding transaction) that fulfils the conditions of the modifier(s)?

@James CARTER Show us the transactions hash

@shadow This is the Hash: 0x2e9fed4fd6271c6605f1819ea32ed45ee719dae2ec5ceacc35c83b4e6e3a74e8

this is the contract @SYEDASADKAZMI 0xe83cE6bfb580583bd6A62B4Be7b34fC25F02910D

You don't have permission to mint(), only the owner does. The owner is 0xAe4799e0CA4C1AC972932a448D7F3dbB205Baf5B. The address calling the mint() is 0x1E6d2D4B3bf4bf9D82a0E5A18F6688B39D9fE733
  modifier hasMintPermission() {
    require(msg.sender == owner);
    _;
  }

It causes this modifier's require statement to fail.
